# WooCommerce product list view: shop by subcategory with shared subcategory image in a list view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Sorry, the title may be confused.

So far, all I find about the product list view for woocommerce are displaying all products under a category with their own images. But what I want is that the products are displayed within a category, for instance:

(in the example, "single Door single drawer bases" is the ultimate subcategory e.g Red cabinet->base cabinet(in red)->single door single drawer bases. in this case all the products in this category with different models are displayed in a list view with shared subcategory image.)

Is there any way (code, plugin or any other idea) to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add the category image to the product list you can use this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_category_image', 100 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
        }
    }
}
```

---

To adjust your product list to your needs you can either modify the template `content-product.php` directly (easy but dirty) or you use the actions hooks in there (recommended but a little bit tricky if you no familiar with this).

Comment: Thank you Andy. I will try what you provided and I will update this thread accordingly later. Thanks again.